# Collapsible in StackEdit

Tags: javascript, html, css, markdown, stackedit

StackEdit deletes certain html tags making it troublesome to implement a collapsible button.

How do you implement collapsible sections in StackEdit?

Comment: Related: https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1329

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Result:

[image]

---

Insert the following CSS into the `<head>` of a StackEdit-template, as well as the following javascript code just above the end of the `body` tag.

```
<style>
/* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
.collapsible {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
}

/* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
.active, .collapsible:hover {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
.content {
  padding: 0 18px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```
<script>
var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var content = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (content.style.display === "block") {
      content.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      content.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
</script>
```

When publishing your page use the template you created, which should look something like:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>{{files.0.name}}</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackedit.io/style.css" />
    <style>
    /* Style the button that is used to open and close the collapsible content */
    .collapsible {
      background-color: #eee;
      color: #444;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: left;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
    }
    
    /* Add a background color to the button if it is clicked on (add the .active class with JS), and when you move the mouse over it (hover) */
    .active, .collapsible:hover {
      background-color: #ccc;
    }
    
    /* Style the collapsible content. Note: hidden by default */
    .content {
      padding: 0 18px;
      display: none;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    
    {{#if pdf}}
    <body class="stackedit stackedit--pdf">
    {{else}}
    <body class="stackedit">
    {{/if}}
    <a href="./" style="
        position:  absolute;
        top:  10px;
        left:  10px;
    ">Back</a>  
    <div class="stackedit__html">{{{files.0.content.html}}}</div>
    
    
    
    <script>
    var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
      coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        var content = this.nextElementSibling;
        if (content.style.display === "block") {
          content.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          content.style.display = "block";
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Collapsible sections can now be created:

```
<div cursor="pointer" class="collapsible">Open Section 1</div>
<div class="content">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```